# присвоение addEventListener переменной. Помогите разобраться, что происходит

Tags: javascript

Я столкнулся с такой вот ситуацией и в образовательных целях интересно понять как это работает.

Я присвоил `this.button.addEventListener` переменной `addHandler` и вызов `addHandler` несколько раз привел к тому, что при нажатии на любое место документа срабатывают события, которые я с помощью этой конструкции повесил.

Почему это работает именно так, я не могу понять. Подскажите.

```js
class Button1 {
  constructor(button, value) {
    this.button = button;
    this.value = value;

    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log(this.value)
    })
  }
}

class Button2 {
  constructor(button, value) {
    this.button = button;
    this.value = value;

    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    let addHandler = this.button.addEventListener;
    addHandler('click', () => {
      console.log(this.value)
    })
  }
}

let button1 = document.getElementById('button_1');
let button2 = document.getElementById('button_2');
let button3 = document.getElementById('button_3');
let button4 = document.getElementById('button_4');
let button5 = document.getElementById('button_5');
let button6 = document.getElementById('button_6');

let newButton1 = new Button1(button1, 'п');
let newButton2 = new Button1(button2, 'а');
let newButton3 = new Button1(button3, 'в');
let newButton4 = new Button2(button4, 1);
let newButton5 = new Button2(button5, 2);
let newButton6 = new Button2(button6, 3);
```

```html
<p>Я думал сработает только событие кнопки, но срабатывает событие кнопки + события трех следующих кнопок. К тому же события трех кнопок срабатывае при клике на любом месте документа</p>
<button id='button_1'>п</button>
<button id='button_2'>а</button>
<button id='button_3'>в</button>
<p>При нажатии на одну, сработает функция всех</p>
<button id='button_4'>1'</button>
<button id='button_5'>2'</button>
<button id='button_6'>3'</button>
```

Comment: Вопрос вообще не подразумевал, что он как-то связан с контекстом вызова. Почему всегда если вопрос хоть как-то В ИТОГЕ ОКАЗЫВАЕТСЯ связан с контекстом вызова, его пытаются отметить как дубликат?

Comment: Я думал, что я присваиваю метод данного конкретного объекта, а в итоге оказалось, что я присвоил переменной метод, который не привязан к конкретному объекту. Ответ в том, что я присваиваю универсальный метод, а не метод конкретного объекта. В итоге решается это с помощью контекста, но изначально вопрос не о том как не потерять контекст

Comment: Но ответ - о том :). Метод все равно привязан к конкретному объекту. Только объект специальный - `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вызов

```
addHandler('click', () => { ...
```

приводит к выполнению функции `addHandler`/`addEventListener` в глобальном контексте. То есть `Button2.init` навешивает обработчик клика на весь документ - три раза в Вашем примере. И они все выполняются на клик в любом месте окна.

Сравните:

```
  init() {
    let addHandler = this.button.addEventListener.bind(this.button);
    addHandler('click', () => { ...
```

Comment: Точно! Спасибо большое!